# list of months and years

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create an Archive, with the number of items per month inside parenthesis, and I have come up with something like this:-

```
@{
  var startMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
  var startYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
  var blogList = Model.BlogViewModel.BlogArchiveList;
  var monthName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
  var Counter = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in blogList)
{
  if (item.BlogDate.Year == startYear)
  {
      if (item.BlogDate.Month == startMonth)
      {
          Counter = Counter + 1;
      }
      else
      {
          Counter = 1;
          startMonth = item.BlogDate.Month;
      }
  }
  else
  {
      Counter = 1;
      startYear = item.BlogDate.Year;
      startMonth = item.BlogDate.Month;
  }
  monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(startMonth);
  @Html.ActionLink(monthName + " " +  startYear + "("+ Counter +")", "Archive", new  
  {
     year=startYear, month=startMonth}) <br/>
  }
```

Although this seems to work, I am getting the month written multiple times if there is more than one entry.

How can I avoid writing the month multiple times, while still getting the count of posts for that month?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: reformatting with indenting I note that you are missing at least one `}`.  Is that the next character or was there more to your code block?

Comment: Oh... and please indent in the future -- you are asking for help, don't make our eyes bleed while we look at your code -- thanks!

Comment: @Hogan sorry I left 1 } out.  How do I indent? Its always a struggle to paste code in the code window

Comment: There is a help button in the editor that explains better than I could, but one way is to put spaces in, as long as a line starts with more than 4 spaces it will format it as code and then spaces matter.  Click on the "edited x mins ago" above my name to see the changes I made -- that should help too.

Comment: Cool thanks Hogan, I will do that for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use next code:

```
var statistics = 
     blogList.GroupBy(val => new {val.BlogDate.Month, val.BlogDate.Year})
             .OrderBy(item => item.Key.Year)
             .ThenBy(item => item.Key.Month)
             .Select (grouped => new {Month = grouped.Key.Month, Year = grouped.Key.Year, Count = grouped.Count() });

foreach (var item in statistics)
{
    var monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.Month);
    Console.WriteLine (string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", monthName, item.Year, item.Count));   
}
```

Prints correct results, for example

```
December 2012 (3)
January 2013 (4)
```

Comment: Thanks Ilya that worked!  Is it ok to include the "var statistics" inside the Partial View or is it better to pass it from the controller?

Comment: you should definitely pass it from controller. Your views should be as simple as possible and controllers too. Pretty much like everything in an application. But anyway - don't calculate statistics in view - it's hard to maintain and test.

Comment: How to do that? I can pass it inside a @ViewBag.statistics, however I have the PartialView embedded in about 3 pages, and I have an ActionResult inside the BlogController, but this is ever triggered.  How can I trigger it?

Comment: See how should model be passed into partial view here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724847/asp-net-mvc-pass-partial-data-model-to-partial-view

Comment: Thanks Ilya.  So I have to pre-populate the ViewModel with the statistics List first.

Comment: yes, note that when you declare statistics you don't actually execute query. The statistics query is only being executed, when you start to iterate over it, i.e. it is differed.

Comment: Cool! How can I convert the statistics to IEnumerable<Blog>? So that I can pass this list to the view through the ViewModel

Comment: Getting an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcJMPortfolio.Models.Blog>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Ok solved!  Created a new class with only the Month, Year and Count and iterated on that.  Thanks a lot Ilya!

Comment: You won't get month without post though

Comment: @remi, that is what I wanted to achieve, I do not need to display a month if there is no post in it